# Sending parameters from React JS to Node JS servers returns as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am sending `uid` to my node JS server in the following way:

```
  fetch(encodeURI("http://localhost:9000/notify", {
        body: JSON.stringify({uid:uid})
      }))
      .then(res => alert(res))
      alert(uid)
```

(the `uid` is a string of numbers)
However, when attempting to read the `uid` in the API, the console returns undefined for body

```
app.get("/notify", async (req, res) => {
  console.log('req.body returns as undefined')
  console.log(req.body.uid)
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: This looks like express; did you enable a [body parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html)? You probably also have to add a `Content-Type: application/json` header to your fetch request. (also note that React is completely irrelevant here)

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` will not send a body on a GET request.

On the client you need to:

- Specify that the `method` is POST (GET is the default)
- Specify the content type request header
- Pass the options object as the second argument to `fetch` and not as the second argument to `encodeURI` (for that matter, don't use `encodeURI` at all, it isn't needed here).

See [MDN: Using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options) for an example

On the server you need to:

- Expect a [POST request](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.post.method) and not a GET request
- Set up [body parsing middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body)